# How to change City field to a dropdown in Checkout step Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I tried multiple solutions found in here, but none seem to fit, the closest one was this one [Magento 2 : How to change UI field(s) dynamically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206201/magento-2-how-to-change-ui-fields-dynamically?newreg=4f03baf9763a4cf9aacc36cc20d77866), here is my implementation of it:

**My\Module\view\frontend\web\js\set-city-mixin.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/utils/wrapper',
'mage/validation'], function ($, wrapper, validation) {
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '[name="country_id"]', function() {
       //for country
       var region = $('select[name="region_id"]');
       changeCity(this, region);
    });

    $(document).on('change', '[name="region_id"]', function() {
       //for province or region
       var country = $('select[name="country_id"]');
       changeCity(country, this);
    });
});
function changeCity(country, region) {
    console.log("change city");
    var cityObject = $('[name="city"]');
    if ($(country).val() == 'CO') {
        console.log('Colombia');
        //send request with country and region and recieve json object
        var response = '[{"name": "Medellin", "code": "50011100"},{"name": "Cali", "code": "50011122"},{"name": "Bogota", "code": "50011133"}]';
        var cities = JSON.parse(response);
        if (cityObject.is('input')) {
            cityObject.replaceWith(function(){
                var select = $("<select>", {
                    html: $(this).html()
                });
                $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute){
                    select.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
                });
              return select;
            });
        } else {
            cityObject.empty();
        }

        if(cities != 'undefined' && cities.length > 0 ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++ ) {
                cityObject.append("<option value="+cities[i].code+">"+cities[i]. name+"</option>");
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (cityObject.is('select')) {
            cityObject.replaceWith(function(){
                var select = $("<input>", {
                    html: $(this).html()
                });
                $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attribute){
                    select.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
                });
              return select;
            });
        }
    }
}

return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
    return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {

        return originalAction();
    });
}
});
```

**My\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Tcc_Shipping/js/set-city-mixin': true
             }
        }
    }
};
```

The result is what I expected to be, but the validation for that field stops working:
[image: Validation error]

Any working alternative would be appreciated too, since what I need is to have a city dropdown with custom codes as values for them.

Comment: Sir did you get the solution of this problem??? if yes can you please share it with me???

Comment: @jacm365, hi, let me know did you found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module, very useful https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

i just had to change this `view/frontend/web/js/form/element/city.js`

line 38

```
romania = obj.RO,
```

for this `obj.CO` just that or if you want to put it dynamically

```
const countryCode = jQuery("select[name='country_id']").val();
romania = (obj[countryCode] !== undefined)? obj[countryCode] : obj.CO
```

Comment: I have used this module but Admin side customer address edit not getting city dropdown value. After change state dopdown city drop down showing blank any idea ?

Comment: Well... I have the same issue, but in my case, the admin does not create the address for the customers, when the customer creates the account and adds the address, it will appear there without  any problem

Answer (score 1):

read this tutorial https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1293

run below code after select city drop-down

var address = checkoutData.getShippingAddressFromData();

address.city = $("#city :selected").text();

checkoutData.setShippingAddressFromData(address);

Answer (score -3):

You can copy the `region.js` file and modify it for city as `city.js`.
And change the city component to change the field type to Select and component type that points to new `city.js` file.

REFER - https://www.magepsycho.com/magento2-region-city-dropdown-manager.html