# Magento 2.3.1 Change city in checkout process from text to dropdown

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3.1

I want to install [this](https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown) module to change city field in checkout process from text to dropdown using composer base on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/248984/81017.

I have tried to:

1. `composer require eadesgin/magento2-city-dropdown:* --no-update`
2. `composer update`

But unfortunately, composer return

> package could not be found in any version

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying with the wrong package name.

https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown/blob/master/composer.json

Please try with this.

```
composer require eadesignro/romcity --no-update
```

This worked for me.

Comment: but its only work on Romania country right !

Comment: i didn't check any country. i have just checked whether composer require is working fine/not.

Comment: Thank you @VenugopalChikkegowda it works perfectly!

Comment: @MuditaWijaya Please are you using the module eadesignro/romcity?

Comment: @MoeHammadi yes I did.